# Solution verification:$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{\ln(x-1)}{3^{x-2}-5^{-x+2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital, solution-verification

> Evaluate without L'Hospital:$$\lim_{x\to
>  2}\frac{\ln(x-1)}{3^{x-2}-5^{-x+2}}$$

My attempt:

I used: $$\lim_{f(x)\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+f(x))}{f(x)}=1\;\&\;\lim_{f(x)\to 0}\frac{a^{f(x)}-1}{f(x)}=\ln a$$

$$
\begin{split}
L &= \lim_{x\to 2} \frac{\ln(x-1)}{3^{x-2}-5^{-x+2}} \\
  &= \lim_{x\to 2} \frac{\dfrac{\ln(1+(x-2))}{x-2}\cdot(x-2)}
                        {(x-2)\cdot\dfrac{3^{x-2}-1+1-5^{-x+2}}{x-2}} \\
  &= \lim_{x\to 2} \frac{\dfrac{\ln(1+(x-2))}{x-2}}
                        {\dfrac{3^{x-2}-1}{x-2}+\dfrac{5^{2-x}-1}{2-x}} \\
  &=\frac{1}{\ln3+\ln5} \\
  &=\frac{1}{\ln(15)}
\end{split}
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: @gt6989b, thank you for responding!

Comment: Thanks you for posting such a well-put and well-formatted question, very few people on the site do that :) If I could +1 again, I would

Comment: It is quite correct.  You could have made it a bit shorter writing  $\;3^{x-2}-5^{-x+2}=5^{-x+2}\bigl(15^{x-2}-1\bigr)$.

Comment: @gt6989b, thank you! I just enjoy this community and owe so much! I never thought the internet would be such a wonderful place for exchanging ideas.

Comment: @Bernard, thank you for noticing!

Comment: Don't use the notation $\lim_{f(x) \to 0}$. The standard notation is $\lim\limits_{\text {variable} \to \text{value}} $. Instead say that you use the limits $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1,\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{a^x-1}{x}=\log a$$ combined with rule for limit of composite functions. Btw +1 as you did solve the problem correctly.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, thank you very much! Your answers were rather useful so, if I learned anything, I owe that to you, too, and other members as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fine. Here is an alternative approach using taylor series:

First substitute $x-2=y$ to simplify it. Let the required limit be $l$. Then
$$l = \lim_{y\to0}\left(\dfrac{\ln(1+y)}{3^y-5^{-y}}\right)$$
$$ = \lim_{y\to0}\left(\dfrac{y-\dfrac{y^2}{2}+\cdots}{(1+y\ln3+\cdots)-(1-y\ln5+\cdots)}\right)$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{\ln3+\ln5}=\dfrac{1}{\ln15}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer a bit rephrased.

$y=x-2;$

$\dfrac{\log (1+y)}{3^y-5^{-y}}$;

Numerator :

$f(y):=y\dfrac{\log (1+y)-\log 1}{y}$

Denominator:

$g(x)=\dfrac{15^y-1}{5^y}=$

$5^{-y}(15^y-1)=$

$5^{-y}(y\log 15)\dfrac{e^{y\log 15}-1}{y\log 15}$;

$\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=$

$[\dfrac{\log (y+1)-\log 1}{y}]\cdot$

$[\dfrac{5^y}{\log 15}]$

$ \big [\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{e^{y\log15}-1}{y\log 15}}\big ].$

Take the limit $y \rightarrow 0$.